# how to get cross streets using foursquare

Tags: foursquare

How do I access the "between X and Y streets" using the Foursquare API?

[image]

Is there a way to query the foursquare API such as when Input=lat/long ; Output =  "On A Street between B and C streets" like in the screenshot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any API that returns a venue object will give you the `crossStreet`. Check out the venues response [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue).

From the response docs the `location` object contains:

> An object containing none, some, or all of address (street address), 
>   crossStreet,  city, state, postalCode,  country,  lat, lng, and
>   distance. All fields are strings, except for lat, lng, and distance.
>   Distance is measured in meters.
>
> Some venues have their locations intentionally hidden for privacy
>   reasons (such as private residences). If this is the case, the
>   parameter isFuzzed will be set to true, and the lat/lng parameters
>   will have reduced precision.

Depending on what your trying to do you can get venue [details](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues), [search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) or [explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) and see the cross street with each.